# How to notify a group in chatter whenever a new case is created

Tags: chatter, case

I wanted to know if there is any way in which we can notify a group in chatter on creation of new case. I'm able to do this in the chatter, but wanted to post it to a specific group.

Comment: This can be done using Process Builder I believe. [This trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-electric-imp/steps/chatter-post) is a good way to start.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Process Builder.

1. Create a new process: set the object to Case, and set the process to start only when a record is created.
2. For the criteria, set the process to "no criteria" so it always executes when a new case is created.
3. For the immediate action, set the action type to "Post to Chatter." Select the option to post to a chatter group and specify the group name. You can also use merge fields from the case in the message, as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Save and activate your process, and you're done.